# What are the browser startup parameters of Firefox when using selenium?

Tags: selenium, firefox

There are no commands without graph mode and some commands that can improve execution efficiency.

### The language I am using is Java,the jar is selenium3,code show as below.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
//This represents running in the background
firefoxOptions.addArguments("--headless");
```

---

I want to know if there are any other orders.
Can improve execution efficiency.

Comment: Please share the code what you have and the problem that you are facing. The parameters are dependent of the project which you are working on.

Answer (score 2):

For headless browser. If you are using webdriver manager you can use following structure as well.

```
WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary();
firefoxBinary.addCommandLineOptions("--headless");
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setBinary(firefoxBinary);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

You can execute parallel test suites, tests or classes. But if your classes depend on another then you have to consider about dependencies as well.

Better if you can use page object model rather than single page scripts and then design your test cases in order to reduce workarounds (better if you can use proper framework).

Another thing is its better if you can pass your test data from DB or excel sheet (this is to reduce code changes etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can set headless firefox as below:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\selenium_drivers\\geckodriver.exe");

//Set Firefox Headless mode as TRUE
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setHeadless(true);

//Instantiate Web Driver
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

To improve execution efficiency you should use selenium implicit wait and fluentwait with element, using Thread.sleep will make your script unreliable and also increase the execution time unnecessary.

You can also use parallel execution which execute 2 or more different suite at the same time, applicable only if modules  or suites are not dependent.